# MySQL faster after restore

Tags: mysql, performance, backup, restore

I have a table with ~300k records, and query with join other table. A query executed about 2 minutes. But! Yesterday I was backup and restore this database and saw, my query faster 10 times! From >100 seconds down ot ~20.  I cant understand, how?
MySQL database 8.0.

Comment: I'd guess some of the tables were badly fragmented, and were not stored efficiently. You might have achieved the same benefit from doing `OPTIMIZE TABLE` on each table (or perhaps only one needed it). Unfortunately, it's not easy to tell which table needs defragmentation.

Comment: It's great news when something good like what you did (reorganize your database's on-disk structure to recover performance) actually works! Happy Friday!

Comment: It is rare for defragmentation to make this much difference.  If you can show us the query and `SHOW CREATE TABLEs`, we might have some other ideas.

Comment: Restart the server; see if it is slow again.  If so, I will explain "caching" and the "buffer_pool".

Comment: Server was restarted many times, but no effect. Speed increased after backup/restore operation.